# Get item in list by startswith

Tags: python

I have the following list:

```
['/my/file.py', 'parallel=2', 'parts=4']
```

How would I extract the '2' in the above? Right now I have:

```
if 'parallel=' in argv:
    parallel = ?? # item.split('parallel=')[1]
else:
    parallel = None
```

Comment: And exactly why doesn't the commented out part not work for you?

Comment: Ad if you are parsing arguments, why not use the supplied [`argparse` library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html).

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Yeah My bad. I thought `argv` is `['/my/file.py', 'parallel=2', 'parts=4']`. Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> v
['/my/file.py', 'parallel=2', 'parts=4']
>>> for thing in v:
        if 'parallel' in thing:
            print thing.split('='), thing.split('=')[-1]
            print thing.partition('='), thing.partition('=')[-1]


['parallel', '2'] 2
('parallel', '=', '2') 2
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use list comprehension :

```
>>> [i.split('=')[1] for i in a if 'parallel' in i]
['2']
```